# Row extraction based on an index in R

Tags: r

A newbie in R.

I have a dataframe data which has a lot of rows in it..

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", header=T)
```

What I want is to extract only rows 20-50 from this whole dataframe.

So,something like row slicing??

```
data.subset <- subset(data,....)?
```

I was trying the approach mentioned in the this site: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-row-slice

But with no luck
How do i do the above?

Comment: Feel free to revert my edit of your Q-title. It's just that "slicing" generally gets used with arrays. Furthermore, the relevant help page is `?Extract`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
data[20:50, ]
```

this will give you rows from 20 to 50. Take a look at [`?"["`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)

Comment: If the OP wanted to use subset, it would be `subset(dat, rownames(dat) %in% 20:50)`